# Is there any more configuration to do when using react-native-marketingcloudsdk?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I followed the step by step in the react-native-marketingcloudsdk Doc
however, no push notification arrives on the device.

I'm currently testing for Android and without success.

But there is success in Journey Builder and the notification does not arrive.

```
// MARKETING CLOUD - SETUP
MarketingCloudSdk.init(this,
    MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
        .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_APP_ID)
        .setAccessToken(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .setSenderId(BuildConfig.FCM_SENDER_ID)
        .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_APP_SERVER_URL)
        .setMid(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_MID)
        .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
    .build(this),
  initializationStatus -> Log.e("SUCCESS - Salesforce Cloud Marketing INIT", initializationStatus.toString()));
```

Comment: 1. Is the device registered?
2. Is the device opted-in?
3. Is the device in the audience list?
4. Was the send successful?
5. What did the feedback service say?
6. What do the Logs say on the affected device? (ref. Android: https://bit.ly/39K1J6f & iOS: https://bit.ly/3jYCiRK)
7. Have they attempted to send a push to the device directly? (ref. Android: https://bit.ly/2RuHPDF & iOS: https://bit.ly/3dJe78f)

Comment: 9.99 times out of 10, you've provided a `senderId`, but you've also included the RNPushNotifications. See: Are they a Multiple Push Provider customer and have they followed the necessary implementation steps? (ref. Android: https://bit.ly/33o8tFF & iOS: https://bit.ly/3eBDE3J)

Comment: Hi @Ronald Silva, can you please share how you have achieve to receive the push notification data in App.js(React Native). 

Currently I am implementing the same, this would helps me.